# how to tick a checkbox using robobrowser

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, checkbox, robobrowser

i'm trying to tick a checkbox on the book which i issued from my college library so ,after doing the login, when i try to select the form and put the value to `1` it gives me a `type error`

here is my code for ticking.

```
box = browser.get_form(action="./selectedBooks")
box['selectedforRenewal'].value = '1'
browser.submit_form(box)
browser.parsed
```

here is the sourcecode.

```
 <form action="./selectedBooks" method="get" id="form1" target="nidhi">
 <input type="checkbox" name="selectedforRenewal" value="0">
```

and the traceback i'm getting.

```
 box['selectedforRenewal'].value = '1'
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

any help with that..

Comment: Well, I have no experience whatsoever with robobrowser but I can tell that what you are trying to do here won't work. You are calling `box['selectedforRenewal'].value` but that is strange since `selectedforRenewal` and `value` are both properties of `input` so it is pretty logical you are getting a `NoneType` error there which indeed is never subscriptable. Also, `.value` in python has a completely different meaning then in HTML so maybe you got those messed up as well? I can't tell from the limited snapshots you've posted.

Comment: @SB87 i did the login on the form using this method .